# deleting a file with a java file

Tags: java, file, path

```
Path to = Paths.get("C:\\submissions\\SOFT222\\Assessment1\\10403435\\Submission15\\OO Java Bootcamp - Java and NetBeans - Copy\\test\\oojavabootcamp\\OOJavaBootcampTestMasase - Copy");
Path from = Paths.get("C:\\submissions\\SOFT222\\Assessment1\\OOJavaBootcampTest - Copy");

void Paths() throws IOException {

    File submissionFolder = new File("C:\\submissions\\SOFT222\\Assessment1\\10403435\\Submission15\\OO Java Bootcamp - Java and NetBeans - Copy");

    if (submissionFolder.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Folder exists");
        try {
            // Remove test files
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(to + ".java"));
            Files.copy(Paths.get(from + ".java"), Paths.get(to + ".java"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Original file copy did not work.");
        }
    }
}
```

This code deletes the .java file but doesn't seem to copy the .java file(OOJavaBootcampTest - Copy) to the 'to' variable cos the name remains the same after deletion has occurred. I think its deleting it and making a copy of it instead of replacing it with the .java in from variable. Please what am I doing wrong

Comment: Why not just go all the way and use a `Path` for your base folder as well? Note that there is `Files.isDirectory()`

Comment: Actually it is working for me, make sure you have file at that location.

Comment: I have had a careful look  and the paths seems alright. my if statement shows the submissionFolder exists but cant find the java file

Comment: Why not check for file itself? Try that once, and use `x.printStackTrace()` Check full exception once.

Comment: please help wit my latest edit

Comment: Sorry but your question still does not make any sense. Why on earth do you now add ".java" at the end? Why don't you just use `Path.resolve()`? Etc etc

Comment: I dont know how that works. I am a novice

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell what the path is which raises the error, so it's hard to tell.

Note that you can:

```
Files.deleteIfExists(somePath);
```

so you may want to use this instead.

---

It's hard to tell what you really want so here I'll just assume that you want to overwrite `to` with `from`; in this case, do:

```
final Path parentDir = to.getParent();

Files.createDirectories(parentDir);
Files.copy(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: I have tried that preciously but doesn't work. The path that causes the error is the 'to' variable

Comment: But what path _exactly_? In fact it is even unclear what you want to do in the first place

Comment: I want to delete the java file in the 'to' variable

Comment: Yes! I want to replace to with from . I have just tried your code but it created a duplicate without deleting the .java file but created a file type File instead. The file in the from directory wasn't copied